# ¿Por qué en Python, al hacer un "scrollview" de botones, cualquiera que escoja con "on_press", siempre me manda el último registro?

Tags: python

Copié íntegro el código que uso, pero para facilitar el  análisis, pueden reemplazar la parte de los datos que uso, para activar el botón y ponerle un texto que me sirva, por cualquier texto simple.
Esta es la parte de código que no me funciona:

```
        filas=miCursor.fetchall()
        if len(filas)!=0:
            for fila in filas:
                self.dato = fila[0] + '\n' + fila[1] + '\n' + str(fila[2]) + str(fila[3])
                self.boton=Button(text=self.dato)
                self.boton.bind(on_press=self.vent_comp)
                self.desplaza.layout.add_widget(self.boton)
```

Comment: El código que has pegado no es reproducible. Quiero decir que no puedo ejecutarlo. Sería conveniente que pusieras un código "completo" (aunque reducido a lo mínimo posible para que aparezca el problema que comentas). Por ejemplo puedes cambiar el `cursor.fetchall()` por una lista "en el código" para no depender así de bases de datos o archivos externos.

Comment: Que error te sucede? Por favor recuerda que si tu código NO es reproducible NI pones el mensaje de error que te da, no tenemos manera de saber que es lo que está sucediendo.

Comment: La voy a poner mas fácil, éste es el código de una aplicación bien simple, de un tutorial de ivandragogear (gracias ivandragogear por tus aportes), yo sólo agregué el comando "on_press" y la función que invoca, lo demás es del programa original y funciona a la perfección, pero también me manda indefectiblemente el último botón:

Comment: Ooops, mandé el mensaje sin el código, ahí va... class Principal(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Principal, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        s="Boton: %s"
        for i in range(30):
            self.sa = s%(i)
            btn = Button(text=self.sa)
            btn.bind(on_press=self.correcto)
            self.ids.container_y.add_widget(btn)

    def correcto(self,*args):
        print ("escogió boton: " + sa)

class MainApp(App):
    title = "Scroll View"
    def build(self):
        return Principal()
Voy a anexar otro mensaje con el código kivy

Comment: Este es el código del archivo kivy (.kv) <Principal>:
  ScrollView:
    GridLayout:
      id: container_y
      size_hint_y: None
   cols: 1
   row_default_height: root.height*0.2
   height: self.minimum_height
Eso es todo, gracias por sus respuestas

Comment: Dentro del bucle for, en cada iteración estás reasignando un nuevo objeto de la clase `Button` a la variable `self.boton`, y también estás reasignando un nuevo valor a `self.dato`. Seguramente dentro del método `self.vent_comp` intentas acceder al valor de estas dos variables, que siempre será el valor asignado en la última iteración del bucle for.

Answer (score 0):

Esta es una solución a mi pregunta:

class Principal(BoxLayout):
def **init**(self,**kwargs):
super(Principal, self).**init**(**kwargs)
s="Boton: %s"
contador = 0
for i in range(30):
self.sa = s%(i)
btn = Button(text=self.sa)
btn.bind(on_press=partial(self.correcto,contador=i))
self.ids.container_y.add_widget(btn)

```
def correcto(self, *args,contador):
    print("*args: ",str(args))
    self.contador = contador
    print (self.contador)
    print ("escogió boton: " + str(self.contador))
```